# How would I make an announcement go to a channel with a certain ID?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

At the moment the channel needs to be mentioned in the message, but I want it to be sent to the channel with ID `497100331956830218`. How can I make it?

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `announce`)) {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {

    let channel = message.mentions.channels.first(); 
    if (!channel) return message.reply("No channel mentioned."); 
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2).join(" "); 

    let split = args.split("-");
    let url = args[2];
    channel.sendMessage("@everyone", { 
      embed: {
        color: 0xFFFF00,
        title: "New Announcement!",
        description: split[0],
        url: split[1],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
          icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
          text: message.author.username
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take your previous code and use [`Guild.channels.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=channels) to get the channel using the ID.

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + `announce`)) {
  if (message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");
    let split = args.split("-");
    let url = args[2];

    let id = 'YOUR ID HERE AS A STRING';
    let channel = message.guild.channels.get(id);
    if (!channel) return message.reply(`Cant find channel \`${id}\` in your guild.`);

    channel.sendMessage("@everyone", {
      embed: {
        color: 0xFFFF00,
        title: "New Announcement!",
        description: split[0],
        url: split[1],
        timestamp: new Date(),
        footer: {
          icon_url: message.author.avatarURL,
          text: message.author.username
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```